# (parse) getting error when updating pfobject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

However simple it may be, I am still struggling to update PFObject data with

```
-(IBAction)postMessageTapped:(id)sender{
    [self hideTextField:_messageTextField];
    NSMutableArray *myNewMessageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [myNewMessageArray insertObject:_messageTextField.text atIndex:0];
    [myNewMessageArray insertObject:[PFUser currentUser] atIndex:1];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:ClassName];

    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:currentId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {


        object[messagingArray] = myNewMessageArray;
        [object saveInBackground];

    }];
}
```

The intent is to get message string from text field and current user name, and put that into an array which then updates the array that exists on the parse database. However,

```
Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)
```

comes up when the user taps the button that posts the message.

Does anyone have a possible solution?

Edit:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:ClassName];


    [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:locationOfSelectedPin];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)  {
        if (!objects) {
            NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
        } else {
            for(PFObject *objectTest in objects){
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved the object.");
            objectTest[@"messagingArray"]=myNewMessageArray;
            [objectTest saveInBackground];
            }
        }
    }];
```

I have also tried using this to update my data, 'successfully retrieved object' gets printed 3 times, but then that is followed by three lines of 'error, object not found for update'.

Answer (score 1):

Check where you are setting `objectId` - this error means it cannot get the object because you are passing a nil value to the database for lookup.

Here's a bit of code to handle the exception:

```
if (!currentId) {
    NSLog(@"Your currentId object is nil! Check your assignment.");
}
else {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:ClassName];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:currentId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    object[messagingArray] = myNewMessageArray;
    [object saveInBackground];
    }];
}
```

Comment: it does seem to be nil... I am using currentId=[NSString stringWithFormat:object[@"objectId"]]; in a previous find object in background query to set the current id string.

Comment: Are you nesting this query to fire only after that one returns? If not, then you might be calling this before the other query has had a chance to find and set currentId. Try nesting this to only fire after that one returns :)

Comment: yep, I made sure that the object id is set before being used in this query. I tried another approach, but that also failed (see the edit)

Comment: Is parse.com returning an error code along with the message? It might be a problem with the ACL table and the error code can help diagnose it.